# Partial type signature

Tags: haskell, ghc, type-inference

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Incomplete type signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11751318/incomplete-type-signature)

Consider the following:

```
import Network.HTTP.Conduit  

(parseUrl "http://stackoverflow.com") :: Maybe a
```

[`parseUrl`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/http-conduit/1.5.0.3/doc/html/Network-HTTP-Conduit.html#v:parseUrl) returns `Failure HttpException m => m (Request m')`

It's documentation says:

> Since this function uses `Failure`, the return monad can be anything
>   that is an instance of `Failure`, such as `IO` or `Maybe`.

However, when I try to force `parseUrl` to use `Maybe`, I get the following error:

```
main.hs:9:11:
    Couldn't match type `a' with `Request m'0'
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
          an expression type signature: Maybe a at main.hs:9:10
    Expected type: Maybe a
      Actual type: Maybe (Request m'0)
```

Is there anyway to force the type to `Maybe` without specifying the full exact type? Answers including GHC extensions are fine.

Note that this works:

```
f :: Maybe a -> Maybe a
f x = x

f (parseUrl "http://stackoverflow.com")
```

But it seems ugly to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `asTypeOf`,

```
main = do
    print (parseUrl "http://stackoverflow.com" `asTypeOf` Nothing)
```

to force the monad to be `Maybe`. Not that that gains much over

```
main = do
    print (parseUrl "http://stackoverflow.com" :: Maybe (Request m))
```

Comment: I've asked a better question regarding this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11751318/incomplete-type-signature