# Incomplete type signature

Tags: haskell, ghc, type-inference

Lets say we've got a function like f below, that returns a monad. However, where you see `Int`, pretend it's a really complicated type.

```
f :: (Monad m) => m Int -- Pretend this isn't Int but something complicated
f = return 42
```

Now lets say we want to force this into the `Maybe` monad. We don't need to write the full type of `f` to do this, we can just do the following:

```
g :: Maybe a -> Maybe a
g = id

main = print $ (g f)
```

The dummy function `g` forces `f` to become `Maybe`.

I think the above is rather messy. What I'd rather write is this:

```
main = print $ (f :: Maybe a)
```

But it fails with the following error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `a' against inferred type `Int'
  `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the polymorphic type `forall a. Maybe a' at prog.hs:7:16
  Expected type: Maybe a
  Inferred type: Maybe Int
In the second argument of `($)', namely `(f :: Maybe a)'
In the expression: print $ (f :: Maybe a)
```

Is there a way to do what `g` above does in a less messy way that doesn't involve creating a new function? I don't want to write `f :: Maybe Int`, as it becomes a maintenance problem if the return type changes. GHC extensions are okay in answers.

Comment: `f \`asTypeOf\` Nothing`, perhaps?

Comment: I can't shake off the feeling that the simplest, best thing you can do here is to define a synonym for `f`'s type.

Comment: See also: [How to define function signatures partially in Haskell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21658438/how-to-define-function-signatures-partially-in-haskell)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`asTypeOf`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v:asTypeOf). It returns the first argument while unifying its type with that of the second. It's just a type-restricted version of `const`, but useful for situations like this.

```
main = print $ f `asTypeOf` (undefined :: Maybe a)
```

Comment: Thanks! People mentioned `asTypeOf` before, but your trick with `(undefined :: Maybe a)` is nicer than actually trying to pick a particular value of the type.

Answer (score 8):

Yet another way is to restrict the type of `print`:

```
main = (print :: Show a => Maybe a -> IO ()) f
```

UPDATE:
GHC 8.0.1 introduced [TypeApplications](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/8.10.7/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#visible-type-application) extension which can be used to force `Maybe`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}

main = print $ f @Maybe
```

Comment: I almost like this better since it doesn't introduce any "accidental" functions and variables.