# Type signature equivalence

Tags: haskell, type-inference

This follows on from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11751318/incomplete-type-signature) question.

Why is:

```
... = ... x :: a ...
```

not defined as

```
... = ... x `asTypeOf` (undefined :: a) ...
```

i.e. in assignment statements, not type declarations?

(Note: `a` could be anything, i.e. `Int`, `a` or `Maybe a`)

As an additional question, what code would break defining `x :: a` as `` x `asTypeOf` (undefined :: a) ``? As in, would it make any valid code invalid or behave differently?

Answer (score 6):

You have to be aware that type variables in type signatures carry an implicit `forall`.

So the signature

```
x :: a
```

means that `x` can have any type, while in

```
x `asTypeOf` (undefined :: a)
```

it's `undefined` that is polymorphic, and its type is coerced to `x`'s type by the use of `asTypeOf`.

So these two do entirely different things.

In the case of the linked question,

```
f `asTypeOf` (undefined :: Maybe a)
```

involves two coercions, on the one hand, the type variable `a` is coerced by `f`'s type, and on the other, the monad in `f`'s type is coerced to `Maybe`.

In response to the edit: A signature

```
x :: Maybe a
```

still promises that `x` can have *every* `Maybe` type. If somebody wants to use it as a `Maybe Bool`, that's possible. As a `Maybe (Either (IO [Int]) (Double, (), Rational))` too.

But in

```
x `asTypeOf` (undefined :: Maybe a)
```

the forall'ed type variable `a` can be refined by `x`'s static type. If that is `Monad m => m SomeComplicatedType`, the expression type signature on `undefined` coerces the type variable `m` in `x`'s type, and the type parameter of `m` refines the type variable `a` from `undefined`'s expression type signature.

If an expression type signature `x :: a` had the semantics of `` x `asTypeOf` (undefined :: a) ``, the current semantics of `x :: a` wouldn't be expressible by expression type signatures anymore.

Comment: Daniel Fischer: I know they're doing different things, as my post admits they're defined differently. I'm asking why they're defined differently. What code would break defining `x :: a` as ``x `asTypeOf` (undefined :: a)``?

Comment: You can't define it as such, since type signatures and expressions are different kinds of things. Since `asTypeOf`'s type makes the coercions/refinements go both ways, the semantics are quite different, and if the semantics of a type signature were like those of ``x `asTypeOf` (undefined :: a)``, you couldn't express the semantics of `x :: a` with type signatures anymore.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. Can you edit your answer to give an example where `x :: a` compiles but ``x `asTypeOf` (undefined :: a)`` doesn't (or produces a different result)? (besides cases where `x` is a definition, not a value).

Comment: Try `True :: a` and `asTypeOf True (undefined :: a)`, the former is a type error, the latter is not.

Comment: augustss, that's still not an answer. We need the reverse situation.