# Can you partially constrain a type in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, type-inference

Is it possible to provide type signatures to Haskell values that contain "blanks" for the type inference algorithm to fill in?

Extremely contrived example for context:

```
m = return ('I', (("don't", "really"), "care", ["what", "this"], "type"), "is") 

b = isJust m
```

This works. The use of `isJust m` in `b` constrains the type of `m` to be `Maybe <something>`, and `m`'s definition constrains the type of `m` to be `<something> (Char, ((String, String), String, [String], String), String)`, and the compiler puts together those two pieces of information to work out the precise type of `m`.

But say I'm not applying any `Maybe` specific functions to `m`, so I'll need a manual type signature to stop the `return` being polymorphic. I can't say this:

```
m :: Maybe a
m = return ('I', (("don't", "really"), "care", ["what", "this"], "type"), "is")
```

because that's incorrect. The type isn't `Maybe a` for all `a`, it's `Maybe a` for some `a` I would like the compiler to infer; there is enough information in the program for the compiler to do this, and we can see from my first example that the compiler *is* able to put together multiple constraints on the type, where no constraint alone is sufficient to figure out what the type is but together they fully specify the type.

What I want is to be able to give types like `m :: Maybe _`, where the `_` means "you figure out what goes here", rather than "this is a rigid type variable" as in `m :: Maybe a`.

Is there some way of saying something like this? The alternatives I can see are explicitly giving the full type:

```
m :: Maybe (Char, ((String, String), String, [String], String), String)
m = return ('I', (("don't", "really"), "care", ["what", "this"], "type"), "is")
```

Or giving a type signature to a part of the expression which has the effect of constraining the `Maybe` part of the type signature but not the `a`, like:

```
m = (return :: a -> Maybe a) ('I', (("don't", "really"), "care", ["what", "this"], "type"), "is")
```

Or leaving `m` without an explicit type signature and introducing unused extra definitions which constrain `m`:

```
m = return ('I', (("don't", "really"), "care", ["what", "this"], "type"), "is") 

b = isJust m
```

Or using a monomorphic function directly:

```
m = Just ('I', (("don't", "really"), "care", ["what", "this"], "type"), "is")
```

Obviously this isn't specific to `Maybe`, nor to the argument of a `* -> *` type constructor; I can imagine wanting to say "this value is a monadic `Int`, for some monad" without wanting to say "this value is a monadic `Int` for *any* monad", or "this is a function from `Int` to some other type" without saying "this is a function from `Int` to *any* other type`.

I'm mostly interested in whether there is something that allows me to fairly directly state declarations like the above about values, for readability purposes, rather than difficult to read workarounds (like giving an explicit type signature for the `return`). I'm aware that if my goal is to simply to get extra typing information into the compiler to shut it up about  ambiguous type variables there are innumerable ways to do that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Incomplete type signature](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11751318/incomplete-type-signature)

Comment: Aren't [holes](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Holes) exactly the solution to this problem?

Comment: @is7s Holes still have to be filled in before the program really works, and I think for Haskell they're really only term-level, not type-level as needed here.

Comment: @DanielWagner in the examples in that link it shows both term-level and type-level holes. AFAIK GHC infers their types correctly, so I don't know why they should be filled if the inferred type is enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GHC 7.10 there is now the [PartialTypeSignatures](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.10.3/docs/html/users_guide/partial-type-signatures.html) extension, which enables exactly the hypothetical underscore syntax I wrote in my question. Examples from the doc page linked above:

```
not' :: Bool -> _
not' x = not x
-- Inferred: Bool -> Bool

maybools :: _
maybools = Just [True]
-- Inferred: Maybe [Bool]

just1 :: _ Int
just1 = Just 1
-- Inferred: Maybe Int

filterInt :: _ -> _ -> [Int]
filterInt = filter -- has type forall a. (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
-- Inferred: (Int -> Bool) -> [Int] -> [Int]
```

With just the `PartialTypeSignatures` extension the compiler issues warnings with the inferred type, in case they were just placeholders you intended to fill in before the final version. With the addition of the `-fno-warn-partial-type-signatures` flag you can tell it that you intended to leave the signatures partial.

Comment: I've written up and accepted my own answer because it's exactly what I was looking for 3 years ago. The other answers are still very useful for older versions of GHC.

Answer (score 6):

GHC doesn't let you specify partial signatures directly, unfortunately, though that would be great to have.

One way to do what you want in this case is `` m = return ... `asTypeOf` (undefined :: Maybe a) ``, where `asTypeOf` is a Prelude function `:: a -> a -> a` that returns its first argument but forces it to unify with the second.

---

That's a good point you make in your comment -- `undefined :: SomeType` makes me sad too. Here's another solution:

```
import Data.Proxy

proxiedAs :: a -> Proxy a -> a
proxiedAs = const
```

Now you can say `` m = return ... `proxiedAs` (Proxy :: Proxy (Maybe a)) ``, and no ⊥s in sight.

Comment: I'd forgotten about `asTypeOf`. That'll work relatively well, although `undefined :: SomeType` always makes me a little sad.

Answer (score 5):

You could write something like:

```
asMaybe :: Maybe a -> Maybe a
asMaybe = id

m = asMaybe $ return ('I', (("don't", "really"), "care", ["what", "this"], "type"), "is")
```

I use this kind of trick in [classy-prelude](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/classy-prelude/0.4.1/doc/html/ClassyPrelude.html#v:asByteString), in providing `asByteString`, `asSet`, `asList`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Synthesising a bit from Michael Snoyman's suggestion, if I:

1. didn't want to have to define a specific function for every type assertion I wanted to make
2. wanted to actually have the type written close to what I was making a type assertion about
3. didn't want to have to write the type twice

I could do something like:

```
type Assert a = a -> a

m = (id :: Assert (Maybe a)) $ return ('I', (("don't", "really"), "care", ["what", "this"], "type"), "is")
```