# How to define function signatures partially in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Starting point:

```
fn :: [a] -> Int
fn = (2 *) . length
```

Let's say we *only* want to constrain the return value, then we could write:

```
fn list = (2 * length list) :: Int
```

How about restricting *only* the argument? Easy.

```
fn list = 2 * length (list :: [Char])
```

While this works, it would be preferable to have the signatures
at the top collected and not scattered around the function body.

This is the closest I could come to this:

```
fnSig = undefined :: [Char] -> a
fn | False = fnSig
   | True  = (* 2) . length
```

Based on http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/partial-signatures.lhs via http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/types.html#partial-sigs

However, I'd like a cleaner solution.
Something that communicates better that my intent is partial restriction.
Something like this, for example:

```
fn :: [Char] -> a
fn = (2 *) . length
```

Or maybe:

```
fn :: [Char] -> _
fn = (2 *) . length
```

Is this possible?

#### Edit for further clarification:

@GaneshSittampalam Made an important point in a comment below.
I am looking for "a half-way house between no type signature at all and having to give a precise one". So, I am not looking for a TypeClass-based answer, I just want GHC to fill in the blanks for the unspecified (or not fully restricted) types of my function.

#### Edit in response to @WillNess

Yes, something like this...

```
fn list = 2 * length list
  where
    _ = list :: [Char]
```

...could work, but only for arguments, and only if the function is not point-free. Is there a way to apply this technique to point-free functions or return values?

#### Edit in response to @Rhymoid

I got inspired, and played around with @Rhymoid's idea, and came up with this:

```
fn = (2 *) . length
  where
    _ = fn `asTypeOf` (undefined :: [Char] -> a)
    _ = fn `asTypeOf` (undefined :: a -> Int)
    _ = fn `asTypeOf` (undefined :: a -> b)
    _ = fn `asTypeOf` (undefined :: a)
```

This approach also restricts fn's type signature, and doesn't pollute any namespace.

Ordinarily we would only have one of the `asTypeOf` lines, I just added multiple to showcase how powerful this approach is.

It is a little more clumsy than how I would like it, but I guess it is pretty neat we can do this even without specific syntactic support from the language.

@Rhymoid, if you like it too, please add it to your answer. :)

Comment: Erm... you can do that in Haskell just fine, only you need of course suitable type-class constraints and polymorphic functions, otherwise it _can't_ work. But consider `fromInteger :: Num a => Integer -> a`.

Comment: What do you intend to do with the result of `[Char]->a`? Short of unsafe cast somewhere else, this way you can only prove the existence of the result.

Comment: It's just about having a half-way house between no type signature at all and having to give a precise one. You can use _ in F# in the way described in this question.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam That exactly what I am looking for! "a half-way house between no type signature at all and having to give a precise one".

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with using the type variable `a` - it *is* not restricting any types, is it? Or is this just about *showing* the intention that it is not restricted?

Comment: @Bergi Was I suggesting there was something wrong with it? Edit: If you are referring to the code blocks #5 and #6 of my question, then yes, `a` and `_` signify unrestricted types.

Comment: @Bergi `fn :: [Char] -> a ; fn list = 2 * length list` [results in compile error](http://ideone.com/XaRBKt) *"Couldn't match expected type `a` with actual type `Int` --
      `a` is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for fn"* -- meaning, since we declare `fn :: [Char] -> a`, the definition can't produce a narrower type than in the *user-given* type signature. The compiler assumes that if the user said `a` (i.e. *any* type), they really meant it.

Comment: @WillNess: A, thanks, now I really got it.

Comment: First, I don't think it is a life-critical feature. It doesn't extend expression power of the language a bit. Second, it will provoke using type inference for top level functions, and it's pretty harmful.

Comment: @Wizek I've edited your post to use (what I consider to be) a slightly more compelling example - a function that is polymorphic in both its input and its return value. If I've misunderstood your question, feel free to shoot me down and change it back to how it was!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Sorry for the self-promotion, but exactly this feature is the topic of a recent paper by Ph.D. student Thomas Winant, myself, Frank Piessens and Tom Schrijvers, very recently presented by Thomas at the PADL 2014 symposium. See [here](https://lirias.kuleuven.be/bitstream/123456789/423475/3/paper.pdf) for the full paper. It is a feature that is already present in some other languages, but the interaction with features like Haskell GADTs made it interesting enough to work out the details.

Thomas is working on an implementation for GHC. It has further improved since the writing of the paper, but implementing the "wildcard constraint" in GHC is technically a bit harder than we expected.  We expect to be able to work further on it and contact the GHC developers to get it adopted, but whether or not this happens may depend on how much people would like to have the feature in Haskell...

Update 14-4-2015: After a lot of work by Thomas and input from SPJ and other GHC people, partial type signatures have been released in GHC 7.10.  Thomas Winant wrote [an introductory blog post](https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/thomasw/new-in-ghc-7-10-partial-type-signatures) about how you can use them.

Comment: You say in the paper you "align with GHC's non-generalisation of local bindings" - does that mean that partial type signatures won't work if you use the `NoMonoLocalBinds` setting to allow those bindings to be generalised anyway?

Comment: Good question.  We haven't looked at that situation yet, but I would expect that in such a case, we should apply the setting to the partial signature.  Anyway, the current plan is to first see if there is sufficient interest in this feature amongst the GHC developers before doing the effort to look at this kind of issues.  (Possible) Interactions with other features like ScopedTypeVariables, RankNTypes, ConstraintKinds also remain to be investigated, for example...

Comment: Not really a GHC developer, but I'd definitely be interested in using this if it were added.

Comment: Marked another answer as accepted because it contains a workaround that is usable right now. I would up vote you twice for your efforts if I could for pushing to make this happen. Looking forward to getting this feature merged upstream. When that happens, I'll probably change the accepted answer accordingly -- since there will no longer be a need for a workaround.

Comment: Also: Judging from the popularity of this question and your answer, it seems to me that there is demand, wouldn't you agree @DominiqueDevriese?

Comment: @Wizek: we hope so, yes. We're preparing some technical material and discussion points and will contact the ghc-devs mailing list soon..

Comment: It looks like you got it in! Could you possibly update your answer to reflect this?

Answer (score 13):

I've been looking for a way to say '`x`'s type unifies with `T`'. The solutions given by Will Ness and chi are close to what I came up with, but there is a way to do it in Haskell 98, without butchering your own function.

```
-- Your function, without type signature.
fn = (2 *) . length

-- The type signature, without actual definition.
fnTy :: [Char] -> a
fnTy = undefined

-- If this type checks, then the type of 'fn' can be unified 
--                                      with the type of 'fnTy'.
fn_unifies_with_type :: ()
fn_unifies_with_type = let _ = fn `asTypeOf` fnTy in ()
```

You could even go for just

```
fn = (2 *) . length
  where
    _ = fn `asTypeOf` (undefined :: [Char] -> a)
```

Comment: More and more creative solutions popping up. Nice. Or maybe it is more correct to call them workarounds, but I do appreciate the creativity. :) I haven't thought about this one. By the way, wouldn't it make sense to write `_ = fn \`asTypeOf\` fnTy` instead of `fn_unifies_with_type = let _ = fn \`asTypeOf\` fnTy in ()`?

Comment: That works too, and is a lot shorter :) You could even go for `_ = fn \`asTypeOf\` (undefined :: [Char] -> a)`.

Comment: One step further: `fn = (2 *) . length where _ = fn \`asTypeOf\` (undefined :: [Char] -> a)` and then it really becomes part of the signature. (If it is outside the where, then the compiler does complain for mismatch, but `:t fn` shows `fn :: [a] -> Int`)

Comment: What do you mean? What makes it less readable? Would you still consider it less readable if it had proper line-breaking and indentation? Also, just to notify: I made an edit to my question in response to your answer.

Comment: I like this ``_ = fn `asTypeOf` (undefined :: [Char] -> a)``. Looks neat.

Answer (score 10):

You're looking for feature that many of us would like, but that Haskell doesn't have.  Nor ghc.  You want a kind of partial type signatures.  The suggested notation for this is

```
fn :: [Char] -> _
fn = (2*) . length
```

Where the `_` means "there's a type here, but I can't be bothered to write it out".

It looks like a very easy feature to implement (instantiate `_` with unification variables in the signature), but nobody has bothered to work out the semantic details and the interaction with other features.

Comment: I see. If so many of us would like it, (and it is even available in F# as noted by @GaneshSittampalam) and it would be easy to implement, how come it isn't added yet? Or even better yet, how could we have it added?

Comment: I thought recently they added "holes" similarly to agda?

Comment: @SassaNF You mean a feature has been recently added that would answer my main question? Could you provide a link so I can read up on it?

Comment: I think holes are at the expression level - you write `_foo` in an expression, and the compiler tells you what type it should have: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/TypeHoles

Comment: @Wizek i don't know how recent that addition is, and whether that will help you, but that's TypedHoles referred to in the previous comment.

Comment: @Wizek SPJ said he would add it if someone shows him what the typing rules are (and it looks reasonable).

Comment: @augustss What do you mean by 'typing rules'? Are those addressed in the paper mentioned by @DominiqueDevriese?

Comment: @Wizek Yes, the paper looks like it has a lot of details.

Answer (score 6):

To specify only the type of an argument, you can write something like

```
fn list = 2 * length list
  where
    a :: [Char]
    a = list `asTypeOf` a
```

So that it is easy to later amend it like, e.g.,

```
fn list = 2 * fromIntegral (length list)
  where
    a :: [Char]
    a = list `asTypeOf` a
```

and have its inferred type change accordingly:

```
*Main> :t fn
fn :: [Char] -> Int
*Main> :r
-- changed file reloaded
*Main> :t fn
fn :: (Num t) => [Char] -> t
```

You could use the same contorted technique to specify the return type of a  function, perhaps defined in [pointfree](/questions/tagged/pointfree) style, but this is not pretty.

```
fn2 list = r
  where
    r :: Int
    r = f list
    f = (2 *) . length
```

It is also not much different from what you have right now, just keeps the code and the type spec separated.

Comment: Thanks for posting! I edited my main question based on your answer.

Answer (score 2):

If the type of your fn can be automatically inferred without a signature, and you merely wish the compiler to check whether the inferred type is of the right form, you might use something along the following.

The idea is to write something such as

```
fnSig :: exists _1 _2. forall a. _1 a -> _2
fnSig = fn
```

except that Haskell does not allow the existential types above. However, existential types can be emulated using higher-rank types as follows:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
fnSig :: (forall _1 _2.
            (forall a. _1 a -> _2)   -- your actual type, _'s are the unknowns
          ->r)->r
fnSig = \k->k fn                     -- the compiler infers _1=[] , _2=Int

-- fn :: [] a -> Int
fn = (2 *) . length
```

The above "trick" is essentially the same as the one used in e.g. runST.

Alternatively, one could declare an ad-hoc existential data type.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
data Ex where Ex :: (forall a. _1 a -> _2) -> Ex
fnSig = Ex fn
```

which should force the compiler to perform the same type checking.

Answer (score 1):

I think you wish for a pretty bad thing. Feature you want slightly increases handiness of type inference, especially for top-level functions. But signatures of top-level declarations represent essential design contracts. They are API, they are documentation, they are beacons for strangers foraying into your code, thus they have to be rock-solid and clear.

Yes, haskell allows type constraints for return types. But this is mostly for temporary results in let-blocks. And yes, you may use

```
 f (x :: Int) = 2*x
```

syntax with XScopedTypeVariables extension (yet it isn't applicable to point-free functions).

Comment: Haskell also allows you to omit those signatures completely. This is no worse.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam But it complains loudly. This is for throw-away code only.

Comment: P.S. And I fear that extending abilities to write throw-away code will turn haskell into throw-away language.

Comment: The same warnings that apply for missing signatures could be turned on for partial signatures.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam Then I don't get the purpose of feature. It will be useless in proper code, yet too monumental for testing one-liners. And read my postscript, please. It's not good to encourage developer's laziness. In a well-designed language one-time code should look ugly as sin, so does current haskell's in-place type binding ^_~.

Comment: Well, I don't entirely agree with your thesis about type signatures, though I do generally use them on top-level declarations in production code. But for me the main advantage would be in auxiliary definitions where type inference fails for some reason and you need to provide a hint - it'd be much nicer to just provide the minimal hint without syntactic overhead.

Comment: When you start doing particularly fancy things, the type signatures can actually start to become a detriment to understanding the code rather than a help because of the proliferation of types in the type signature that is important for the implementation but not important for the programmer. Consider the typeclass `Semiring u t | u -> t, t -> u` that combines two monoids together to give both a multiply and an addition operation over t, by marshalling it to the isomorphic u monoid as needed. In `(*) :: Semiring u t => t -> t -> t`, the user doesn't care about `u`, `_` is clearer.

Comment: @BarendVenter You're talking about discrete thing. In your case compiler can just replace wildcard by some random unique type variable, while OP wants it to perform full-featured W-algorythm on it. P.S. And abstract algebra isn't a rocket science, I don't see what's so 'fancy' there.

Comment: @user3974391 No that is wrong, in the case I was using as an example, the compiler can't simply come up with some random unique type variable because of the functional dependency. It will have to do some kind of inference to figure out what to put into the wildcard once it knows what `t` is. Also it was fancy because it used extensions like multi-parameter type-classes and functional dependencies, as is common in Haskell libraries. It was meant to illustrate an example where type information is necessary but also not useful in understanding code.

Comment: @BarendVenter No, it can. Try to replace 'u' in (*) with random type variable, your code will still compile. Hint: type variables aren't scoped in this case.